# Shannon's entropy as a measure of vocabulary richness

Tags: computational-linguistics, vocabulary, quantitative-linguistics, entropy

The Entropy formula for lexical richness is

[image]

The probability p-ith is calculated by dividing V-ith by N, where N is the total number of tokens in the text and V is the number of types. However, I can't seem to grasp the concept of V-ith? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Source: Dale, Moisl, and Somers (p.551). "Handbook of Natural Language Processing" (2000).

Comment: Edition 1 or 2 of the book?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt https://books.google.at/books?id=VoOLvxyX0BUC&pg=PA551&lpg=PA551&dq=entropy+vocabulary+richness&source=bl&ots=wucWFF1Rn_&sig=Hms1qwhXlcOaPEXI84eDqxsTEdo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIjvvQnvPVxwIVhJ5yCh35ZAb_#v=onepage&q&f=false
This one.

Comment: This exact question has been asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350202/lexical-richness-as-shannons-entropy-python. It is still waiting for an answer, too, but the question provides more information.

Comment: @Adam_G I'm also the one who asked the other question on stakoverflow, but it doesn't seem like it's getting an answer anytime soon.

Comment: V(i) seems to be the number of tokens of type (i). When v(i) is devided by N (total number of tokens) it yields an estimation for the probability of the type (i) [p(i) = V(i) / N].

Answer (score 1):

The entropy formula as quoted has some ideosyncrasies making it different from standard Shannon entropy

- There is a (not really relevant) factor of `100` (probably to produce more beautiful numbers)
- The term `log N` in the denominator is absent in Shannon entropy

The term *p(i)* cannot mean anything but the frequency of the i-th type, obtained by dividing the number of occurences of it by the total number of tokens. The frequency equals the probability in a bag-of-words (or more general, a bag-of-types) model.